# File handling using C++ with OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, file-handling

I am using OpenMP in C++ for parallel processing. The size of a file being handled is about 40GB. Simple searching of a string from another file in this large file takes very long time, as strings from the other file could appear many times in the large file so every time it has to search the complete file.

Any idea I could try in order to speed up the process more?

Comment: OpenMP can only speed up tasks which are CPU-bound, not those which are I/O-bound.

Comment: there exists parallelized IO if you use an corresponding file system which allows for parallelized access like [PFVS](http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/tech_reports/reports/P804.pdf) additionally there is [MPI IO](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node52.html) but I don't know if an MPIIO variant exists for openmp.

Comment: OpenMP is not really meant for that; threads would be a more suitable tool. In any case, you can open the file multiple times for reading using different streams. Each thread can take one stream and can reposition the stream indicator using fseek() or something similar from the OS so that each thread has its own range to check.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you divide the file into two or more parts depending on the no. of threads and search on them in parallel